# Sping Boot - Separate config file other than application.yaml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a spring boot maven java application. I have the application.yml file and the properties specified here are used by a jar dependency of the project and I want to keep this file for them dependencies alone.

There is some additional config I want to use in the application. Is there a way to specify a second configuration file to be used within the project?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@PropertySource({"classpath:first.properties", "classpath:second.properties"})` like given below,

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class MySeparateProperties
{
 @Value( "${property.path.name}" )
 private String prop;

}
```

Now use this bean to use the properties where ever you want in your application

The only issue is that, if the property path is same for `application.yml` and `config.properties` application.yml will have higher priority

Edit 1

If the file is located at `resources/config/config.properties` then you have to give `classpath:config/config.properties`

Comment: I have tried this but get Could not resolve placeholder 'db.resources.name' in value "${db.resources.name}"

Comment: Do i need to change classpath to my actual classpath or should writing "classpath" be eniugh

Comment: Just writing classpath is enough but make sure to give the exact path from your resources

Comment: Issue was a was trying to use a yaml file for the properties, when i changed to a .properties file it worked. Accepting this answer as was easiest to follow with the example plus follow up questions were answered. Thanks

Comment: It is important to notice:
1. yaml files arent supported currently, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18486
2. it is possible to use outer files like from Git via Spring Cloud Config Server

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a different name using the property `spring.config.name`.

[From the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files):

> If you do not like application.properties as the configuration file name, you can switch to another file name by specifying a spring.config.name environment property.

Comment: I don't want to switch from using application properties, i wish to use an additional file as well as it.  Where can i find that spring.config.name property in my application do you know?

Comment: I'm a little confused now. You said you want to leave the `application.properties` to a dependency to use. You need to specify a different naming for your application to pick up a separate file. By doing that, you can have the `application.properties` and also `your-whatever-custom-name.properties`.

Comment: Where do we set the spring.config.name property?

Comment: Either OS environment var or application argument like this: `java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=myproject`

Answer (score 1):

Create property file as example x.properties and use @PropertySourse(“classpath:x.propeties”)
 When need to use it

Comment: I have tried this but get Could not resolve placeholder 'db.resources.name' in value "${db.resources.name}" , Do i need to change classpath to my actual classpath or should writing "classpath" be enough

Answer (score 1):

Configuration files can be set by spring properties, you can use:

- spring.config.name to select the names of the configuration files (separated by comma)
- spring.config.location to set the paths where the configuration files are located (separted by comma)

Try to look at [springboot reference doc here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) for details.